# What is the meaning of "It is amazing the support we get from the community"?

Tags: meaning, grammar

What is the meaning of "It is amazing the support we get from the community" ?
Does "It is amazing the support we get from the community" mean "The support we get from the community is amazing" ?

Is "the support" being used as a subject, not an object? 
If yes, what grammars can explain the composition of these sentences?
Are there many similar types of examples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are exactly correct. ***It*** refers to the ***support of the community***.

I think, technically, there should be a comma:

> It is amazing, the support we get from the community.

Similarly, you could say:

> The support we get from the community, it is amazing.

Also common, and perhaps even preferable:

> It is amazing -- the support we get from the community.
>
> The support we get from the community -- it is amazing.

(This is a nice page on how to use the emdash: http://www.thepunctuationguide.com/em-dash.html)

In all these cases, ***the support we get from the community*** describes ***it.*** These examples are typical of spoken and informal usage. In formal usage, the "it" would be considered redundant and therefore incorrect. I don't think there's a particular term to describe this kind of sentence construction. It's very typical in speech patterns. People say a pronoun, and then clarify the meaning of the pronoun. For example, you would use this kind of construction often if you were writing dialogue for a novel. It suggests to the listener/reader that this is a realistic  representation of how that person speaks.